# Magento: How to remove particular store from Store View Switcher

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13

I am using Magento 1.13.

I have 4 stores and want to remove one from the Store Switcher.

Went to System > Manage Stores
I disabled store view and cleared cache and also reindexed.

But front-end store switcher, still shows the link of that disabled store.

How to remove the link from Store View Switcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using switch.phtml
The file I found it in
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/page/switch

Changed the foreach loop to exclude the store.